# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error rsa encryption

Tags: java

Im testing: Server encrypting of public key message and sending to client, that should decrypting message, but called Exception.

Server

```
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("New client connected");
            output = socket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            String message = "Hello there?";
            byte[] encbyte = rsa.encryptByPublicKey(message.getBytes(), publickey);
            String enc = new BigInteger(1, encbyte).toString(); 
            System.out.println("enc " + enc );

            dOut.writeInt(encbyte.length);
            dOut.write(encbyte);

            byte[] decodebyte = rsa.decryptByPrivateKey(encbyte, privatekey); //test
            String decodedata = new String(decodebyte);
            System.out.println("decodedata " + decodedata);

            while (true);
```

Client

```
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5556);
            key = rsa.initKey();
            publickey = rsa.getPublicKey(key);
            privatekey = rsa.getPrivateKey(key);

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            Thread.sleep(300);
            System.out.println("connected");

            byte[] array = null;
            int length = dIn.readInt(); // read length of incoming message
            if(length>0) {
                array = new byte[length];
                dIn.readFully(array, 0, array.length); // read the message
            }

            String enc = new BigInteger(1, array).toString();
            byte[] decodebyte = rsa.decryptByPrivateKey(array, privatekey); //error
            String decodedata = new String(decodebyte);
            System.out.println("decodedata " + decodedata);
```

I use this library (rsa decrypting and encrypting)

```
public class rsa {
    public static final String KEY_ALGORITHM = "RSA";
    public static final String SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = "MD5withRSA";

    private static final String PUBLIC_KEY = "RSAPublicKey"; //RSAPublicKey
    private static final String PRIVATE_KEY = "rsa"; //RSAPrivateKey

    public static byte[] decryptBASE64(String key) throws Exception {
        return Base64.getDecoder().decode(key);
    }

    public static String encryptBASE64(byte[] key) throws Exception {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key);
    }

    public static byte[] decryptByPrivateKey(byte[] data, String key)
            throws Exception {
        // 对密钥解密
        byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(key);
        
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        Key privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);

        
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    }

    public static byte[] decryptByPublicKey(byte[] data, String key)
            throws Exception {
        // 对密钥解密
        byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(key);

        // 取得公钥
        X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        Key publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);

        // 对数据解密
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    }

    public static byte[] encryptByPublicKey(byte[] data, String key)
            throws Exception {
        // 对公钥解密
        byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(key);

        // 取得公钥
        X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        Key publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);

        // 对数据加密
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    }

    public static byte[] encryptByPrivateKey(byte[] data, String key)
            throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(key);

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        Key privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    }

    public static String getPrivateKey(Map<String, Object> keyMap)
            throws Exception {
        Key key = (Key) keyMap.get(PRIVATE_KEY);

        return encryptBASE64(key.getEncoded());
    }

    public static String getPublicKey(Map<String, Object> keyMap)
            throws Exception {
        Key key = (Key) keyMap.get(PUBLIC_KEY);

        return encryptBASE64(key.getEncoded());
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> initKey() throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator
                .getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        keyPairGen.initialize(1024);

        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGen.generateKeyPair();

        // 公钥
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();

        // 私钥
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();

        Map<String, Object> keyMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);

        keyMap.put(PUBLIC_KEY, publicKey);
        keyMap.put(PRIVATE_KEY, privateKey);
        return keyMap;
    }
}
```

What could be the problem? Library? Message? I checked message, and length on client and server same
Worked great on one project.
Thank for the help.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You generate one key pair in Server, and then you generate another key pair in Client. There is no chance you can decrypt by a key from one pair a message encrypted by a key from another pair.

Comment: But shouldn't the private key for decryption be created inside the client, and not sent? How else? Thanks

Comment: You should be encrypting the message you want to send with the public key of your counter party. And try RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding, although RSA is regarded as insecure afaik

Comment: The privatekey should be created by the decrypter and kept private (not sent); the publickey should _also_ be created by the decrypter and _must_ be sent at least to the encrypter(s); often it is sent to everybody, because you don't always know in advance who will be sending encrypted messages to a given party. See the first two graphics at the right-side of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography .